# Display legend for RowSideColors in heatmaps.plus

Tags: r, heatmap

I am using heatmaps.plus to create heatmaps with RowSideColors.  The only thing I can't seem to figure out is how to make a legend for the RowSideColors (for example, green is Group1 and black is Group2).  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Please provide us a reproducilbe-example (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You should use `legend` for this.

```
library("heatmap.plus")

#Create dummy data
data <- replicate(10, rnorm(10)) 
rsc <- c("green", "green", "black", "green", "green", "black", "black", "green", "green", "black")
rsc <- cbind(rsc, rsc)
colnames(rsc) <- c("Groups", "")

#Plot
heatmap.plus(data, RowSideCol = rsc)

#Legend on position (40, 2)
legend(40, 2,legend=c("Title","","Group1","Group2"), fill=c("white", "white", "green","black"), border=FALSE, bty="n", y.intersp = 0.7, cex=0.7)
```